# Firebase Custom event - firebase parameters not visible in dashboard

Tags: android, events, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm making an `Android` game, where I want to track with `Firebase Analytics`, how users spend their different ingame currencies. For this, I wrote the following method:

```
public void trackInAppUpgrades(String id, int upgradePrice, String currencyName) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
    bundle.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, (double)upgradePrice);
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(currencyName, bundle);
}
```

I've used predefined parameters like ITEM_ID and VALUE and send the event with the name of my currency, as there are several currencies and I want to distinguish them as separate events.

However, when I look at the firebase console and select the event from events, I do not see the parameters I have added to this event:

[image]

24hours have passend and there isn't more to see. I've read in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) that custom parameters will not show up in the report, but what about custom event with prescribed parameters?

Do I really need to use the predefined `events` by Google to see any parameters I want to track?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482478/how-to-add-firebase-custom-events-for-analytics/40485207#40485207, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604275/how-to-view-event-parameters-from-firebase-console

Comment: have you founnd solution to your problem?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately not, I went with standard parameters, I was not quite happy with this.

Comment: I'd suggest trying the debug view for firebase to ensure that the event you're trying to record is being received.  You could also pipe your data to Big Query and verify if it's there.