# Unable to view event parameters on Firebase console

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I'm trying to track additional parameters for events using the Firebase API as shown below. However I'm unable to view the data on the Firebase console.

```
+(void)uploadEventsToFireBase:(NSString *)eventString withParams:(NSDictionary *)params
{
    if (params == nil)
    {
        [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:eventString parameters:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        for (NSString *paramKey in [params allKeys])
        {
            [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:eventString
                            parameters:@{
                                         kFIRParameterItemID:paramKey,
                                         kFIRParameterItemName:params[paramKey],
                                         kFIRParameterContentType:eventString
                                         }];
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to get this to work ? I'm using the following versions of their SDK

Firebase 3.16.0

FirebaseAnalytics 3.8.0

Comment: See the second question in the "Related" column: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604275/how-to-view-event-parameters-from-firebase-console?rq=1

Comment: tried those suggestions, still not seeing any updates on the console

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are logging custom events. Only predefined events have some built-in reports. According to the official website https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events,

> Custom parameters: Custom parameters are not represented directly in
>   your Analytics reports, but they can be used as filters in audience
>   definitions that can be applied to every report. Custom parameters are
>   also included in data exported to BigQuery if your app is linked to a
>   BigQuery project.

Custom parameters should always arrive with your events. However, custom parameters are used in Audience in the SDK and if there is an audience that matches your definition, they will be reported to the server. You just cannot see them in the report for now.

Answer (score 2):

The test on the official website has changed now to:

> Custom parameters: Custom parameters can be registered for reporting in your Analytics reports. They can also be used as filters in audience definitions that can be applied to every report. Custom parameters are also included in data exported to BigQuery if your app is linked to a BigQuery project.

In the console under "Analytics / Events" there are three dots on the right hand side of each event. Clicking there shows the menu item "Edit Parameter Reporting". There you have access to the custom parameters, and you can add them to the reporting.

Comment: But the Edit Parameter Reporting option is now gone, is there's an update to this?