# How to view the parameter values of a Firebase event?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

When a Firebase event fires a few times from an app, it soon appears in the Firebase dashboard event session listing. By default, as soon as a custom event appears there, it is already possible to view the number of occurrences, number per user, number in the last 30 minutes, per country, etc.

However, until today I didn't understand how I can visualize in detail the values that are sent to the parameters of these events.

For example: Suppose I have a car game where the user has thousands of different car options to choose from. Soon I would have an event called "select_car" that would be fired whenever a user selects a car, and as a parameter I would send the model of the chosen car, for example "car_model" that can have any model as a value, for example: Ferrari, Fiesta , Uno, Golf, etc.

**That said, how and where do I view the report that will be generated after a long period of collecting event data, to gain insights, for example, which car is being chosen the most in a given period?**

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604275/how-to-view-event-parameters-from-firebase-console?

Comment: I just saw this question. So at the end of the day the definitive answer is in this right video (https://youtu.be/o3J0zuaX9M0)?

I know it's not much use complaining, but I got the impression that this is much more difficult than it should be, all I need is just a simple data crossing, from the tutorial I saw that it is a relatively complex process and that it takes up to wait 24 hours after registering a dimension. Do you, or anyone reading this, have any recommendations for a service that would solve the problem (collecting events and visualize reports crossing data) more easily?

Comment: Good to hear you got it working Antonio. Any chance you can write up what you actually did in an answer below, so that others can benefit from that?